# What is the difference between android shared memory api and content provider?

Tags: android

Android shared memory api(which is introduced in api 27) is used for sharing data between different process. So is it a replacement of content provider?

Answer (score 1):

If you have a relatively small collection of **key-values** that you'd like to save, you should use the [SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences.html) APIs, but it is not multi-process safe.

[SharedMemory API](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/SharedMemory.html) (which introduce in Android 8) allows you to reading and/or writing **file descriptor** using **NDK**, since the SharedMemory object is Parcelable, you can easily pass it to another process through **AIDL**. It's a great way to **set the memory protection** and share large amounts of data between apps or between  multi-process within a single app.

[ContentProviders](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/content-provider-basics.html) were constructed for **sharing data between apps**. A content provider presents data to external applications as one or more tables that are similar to the tables found in a relational database. You can create your own ContentProvider which stores the data with a SharedPreference, you don't have to use SQLite. The ContentProvider APIs are well suited for SQL type implementations.

Comment: No dude. Im talking about shared memory api which is introduced in api 27

Comment: @Anko6 sorry. So please edit and add more detail on your question